# Как правильно реализовать функцию в шаблон. Ansible

Tags: ansible

Есть шаблон:

```
{% if {{ dbtype }} is 'pg' %}
DATABASES = {{ '{' }}
    {{ local_def }}: {{ '{' }}
        {{ local_engine }}: 'django.{{ dbtype }}', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        {{ local_name }}: '{{ username }}', # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        {{ local_user }}: '{{ username }}',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        {{ local_pass }}: '{{ username }}',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        {{ local_host }}: '{{ pg_dbhost }}',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        {{ local_port }}: '{{ pg_dbport }}',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    {{ '},' }}

{{ '}' }}
{% endif %}
{% if {{ dbtype }} is 'mysql' %}
DATABASES = {{ '{' }}
    {{ local_def }}: {{ '{' }}
        {{ local_engine }}: 'django.{{ dbtype }}', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        {{ local_name }}: '{{ username }}', # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        {{ local_user }}: '{{ username }}',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        {{ local_pass }}: '{{ username }}',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        {{ local_host }}: '{{ mysql_dbhost }}',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        {{ local_port }}: '{{ mysql_dbport }}',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    {{ '},' }}

{{ '}' }}
{% endif %}
```

Сценарий должен скопировать шаблон на сервер и подставить переменные. Но при выполнении выдет ошибку:

```
AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token 'name', got 'string'. String:
```

Как я понял, проблема в **{% if {{ dbtype }} is 'mysql' %}** ?

Выполняеться он через template

```
- name: Create local.py 
  template:
    src: local.py
    dest: "{{ user_home }}/{{ username }}/settings/local.py"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

надо просто **is** заменить на **==**

```
{% if dbtype == 'mysql' %}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает)

Comment: Я понимаю, что так изощренно сознаться в своих недостатках - занятно :) Но всё ж стоит избегать сильных выражений :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Я убрал это сильное выражение и дух восстановил справедливость... поставив минус за редактирование)))

Comment: Извините. Просто когда пол дня неможешь понять в чем проблема, но потом оказываеться что ошибка в маленьком слове из двух букв... начинает гореть задний привод... Буду знать))